# Is there a more efficient way of reading and writing a text fill at the same time?

Tags: c#

I'm back at it again with another question, this time with regards to editing text files. My home work is as follow

`Write a program that reads the contents of a text file and inserts the line numbers at the beginning of each line, then rewrites the file contents.`

This is what I have so far, though I am not so sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it. I've only started learning on handling text files at the moment.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Chapter 15\Chapter 15 Question 3\Chapter 15 Question 3\TextFile1.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);

        int lineCounter = 0;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        using (reader)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                list.Add("line " + (lineCounter + 1) + ": " + line);
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                lineCounter++;
            }
        }

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        using (writer)
        {
            foreach (string line in list)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

your help would be appreciated!
thanks once again. :]

Comment: You really think looping twice is efficient?

Comment: It could be done with a `StreamReader` to use less memory; write to a diffent file that is renamed afterwards while the original file is deleted.

Comment: @Codor That sounds like a great idea actually! I never thought of writing to another file and changing its name to the previous file's name. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Note that you can do `using(var reader = new StreamReader()){...}` in this way the compiler warns you that you can't use `reader` after the using statement's closing bracket.

Comment: Btw in what kind of way do you want it to be efficient? Do you want it to be fast/easy to write, fast to execute, or to use little memory?

Comment: @Roy T. I meant efficient in terms of speed. It seems that if I have to loop twice, one for reading and one for writing, the time it would take would be proportional to the length of the text. Given a long enough text it would take a longer period of time. Always looking to improve my code. Thanks mate.

Comment: Think about this again. How can you add a line number in front of every line without taking time in proportion to the length of the text? That's quite impossible :). If you've read about Big-Oh this problem is in O(n) where n is the length of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Linq`, use `File.ReadLines`to read the content.

```
// Read all lines and apply format
var formatteLines = File
  .ReadLines("filepath")  // read lines
  .Select((line, i) => string.Format("line {0} :{1} ",  line, i+1)); // format each line.

// write formatted lines to either to the new file or override previous file.
File.WriteAllLines("outputfilepath", formatteLines);
```

Comment: We actually haven't started learning on Linq yet. So I had to come up with something else. It seems that alot of data things can be made simpler with the use of Linq. In due time of course. Hehe

Comment: Just a note,  this answer loops through the entire file twice (as all entries will). Its just hidden in the ReadLine and WriteAllLines functions. This answer is equivalent to the one by Nino and the Linq code will result in almost exactly the same code, which is fine :).

Answer (score 2):

this should be enough (in case the file is relatively small):

```
using System.IO;    
(...)

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string fileName = @"C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Chapter 15\Chapter 15 Question 3\Chapter 15 Question 3\TextFile1.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    for (int i = 0; i< lines.Length; i++)
    {
        lines[i] = string.Format("{0} {1}", i + 1, lines[i]);
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one loop here. I think it will be efficient.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\MyText.txt";

        StreamReader sr1 = File.OpenText(path);


        string s = "";
        int counter = 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((s = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var lineOutput = counter++ + " " + s;
            Console.WriteLine(lineOutput);

            sb.Append(lineOutput);
        }


        sr1.Close();
        Console.WriteLine();
        StreamWriter sw1 = File.AppendText(path);
        sw1.Write(sb);

        sw1.Close();

    }
```

Comment: this won't work well. First of all, numerated lines are appened at the end of original file. Second, that appened text is in one line. Check your "solution" before posting. Use `sb.AppendLine(lineOutput)` and `File.WriteAllText(path)`